# Ajax request not returning a response

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to send an Ajax request on click of a button, but I can't seem to get the controller to return a response. The response is empty; what might be the problem?

**View**

```php
<a href="#" onclick="addtoCart(1, 'test', 2, 8900)"
   class="btn essence-btn">Add to Cart</a>
<div hidden id="url" data-url="{{ url('/cart/add') }}"></div>
```

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

function addtoCart(id, name, quantity, price) {
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/cart/add",
        method: 'POST',
        data:
            {
                id: id,
                name: name,
                quantity: quantity,
                price: price
            },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'cart'], function () {
    Route::post('/add', 'CartController@add');
});
```

**Controller**

```php
public function add(Request $request) {
     return Response::json($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Try returning just a string, for testing, see if that is passed back.

Comment: Still returns nothing.

Comment: Which HTTP Code has your response? You can analyze the request for example with the Chrome Dev. tools.

Comment: It returned 200

Comment: What if you change ``Route::post`` to ``Route::get`` and open up the url in your web browser? Do you get any response?

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your code like below. I think it will be help you.**

Here is the route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'cart'], function (){
   Route::post('/add', 'CartController@add')->name('add-cart');
});
```

Here is the script

```
function addtoCart(id, name, quantity, price) {
  $.post('{{ route('add-cart') }}', {id:id, name:name, quantity:quantity, price:price}, 
    function (data) {
     console.log(data);
  }
}
```